# Bartle Theorem 3.1.10 (Sequence section) Proof Question

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need some help to understand the proof of this theorem below. I tried several times to understand the proof, but I failed.

Specifically, I do not understand how and why you get $\mathbf{K} = \mathbf{K}(\frac{\epsilon}{\mathbf{C}})$

Until now I was familiar with getting K to be something like $\mathbf{K} > \frac{\epsilon}{\mathbf{C}}$ and then proceed to proof the limit of a sequence. However, in the proof below, equality is used instead of inequality and $\mathbf{K}$ is assigned with itself with some constant $\frac{\epsilon}{\mathbf{C}}$.

[Theorem 3.1.10 Sequence Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPC0H.png)

Comment: $K=K(\frac {\epsilon} {C})$ simply means $K$ could possibly depend on $\epsilon$ and ${C}$.

Comment: More precisely, $K$ depends on $\epsilon/C$.

Comment: @Julián
Thank you! Now I understand the proof.

Comment: @Kavi 
Thank you! Now I understand the proof.